# Find multiple most recent dates before a given date efficiently?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query takes 1.5s and because I need to run it several thousands times, I would like to optimize it. Basically I try to find the first date less than or equal to an array of provided dates (e.g. `['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01']`). Now I'm doing each date individually:

```
SELECT date FROM date_history
     WHERE ticker = 'APPL' AND date <= %(date)
     ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I feel as though it might be faster if I could reuse the date sorting or something under those lines but I can't think of a good way to do this. Any suggestions on how to make this faster would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte(d) AS (
   VALUES ('2016-01-01'::date)
          ,('2017-01-01'::date)
          ,('2018-01-01'::date)
   --Or unnest array_variable WITH ORDINALITY
), cte2 AS (
SELECT d.date, c.d,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.d ORDER BY d.date DESC) AS rn
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN date_history d
  ON d.date <= c.d
WHERE d.ticker = 'APPL' 
)
SELECT c.d, d.date AS max_date_before
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY c.d ASC;
```

---

Alternatively `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` and correlated subquery:

```
WITH cte(d) AS (
       VALUES ('2016-01-01'::date)
              ,('2017-01-01'::date)
              ,('2018-01-01'::date)
       --Or unnest array_variable WITH ORDINALITY
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte c,
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date_before
                   FROM  date_history d
                   WHERE d.ticker = 'APPL' 
                     AND d.date <= c.d) s;
```

Comment: Hum... I think it may be a little more difficult than this (unless I'm misunderstanding) because I essentially just want to join the first row of each of these queries but here it is joining the entire table of smaller dates not just the 1st-smallest-or-equal-date.

Comment: @nico Does it work or not? You will join multiple values but still get the first lowest one (`ORDER BY c.ord ASC, d.date DESC LIMIT 1`) will handle it

Comment: I ran your query and it only display the result for the first date ('2015-12-31') not the others.

Comment: @nico So you want smallest per group I will upate my answer

Comment: Looks good. There were a few typos I'll suggest edits for but this runs in 1.5s meaning it hardly takes longer than one query. Thanks!

Comment: @nico Great to hear it